# assign the value of a select to a variable plpgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js, plpgsql

I'm trying to create a trigger in the Bank that when you get a new service record, it checks if all services are finished and update a specific field.

I don't know plpgsql and I'm having difficulty with that.

Can anyone help me?

This is the code I made so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_finished_service_procedure() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
        $$
          DECLARE 
            isSearchFinished RECORD;
          BEGIN
            RAISE LOG 'Service finalized: %', NEW;
            
            SELECT 
              bool_and(ss."finishedProcessingAt" IS NOT NULL) AS "isAllServicesFinished",
              s."finishedCriminalAt" AS "finishedCriminalAt"
            FROM "SearchesServices" ss
            INNER JOIN "Searches" s ON s.id = ss."SearchId" 
            WHERE ss."SearchId" = NEW."SearchId"
            GROUP BY s."finishedCriminalAt"
            INTO isSearchFinished;

            IF isSearchFinished.isAllServicesFinished = true 
            AND isSearchFinished.finishedCriminalAt IS NOT NULL THEN
              UPDATE "Searches" s
              SET "finishedProcessingAt" = now()
              WHERE s.id = NEW."SearchId";
            END IF;  
            
            PERFORM * FROM aws_lambda.invoke(
              'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:${awsId[env]}:function:bgc-candidate-manager-${env}-CheckWebhookNotification',
              jsonb_build_object(
                'searchId', NEW."SearchId"
              ),
              'us-east-1',
              'Event'
            );
            RETURN NEW;
          END
        $$;
```

But when I try to run, I get this error:

```
Error synchronizing data with database

Reason:
SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: record "issearchfinished" has no field "isallservicesfinished"
  Onde: SQL statement "SELECT isSearchFinished.isAllServicesFinished = true 
            AND isSearchFinished.finishedCriminalAt IS NOT NULL"
PL/pgSQL function notify_finished_service_procedure() line 15 at IF
```

how do i make it work?

Comment: Don't use mixed case identifiers. If you want to go that route you need to quote them everywhere you use them e.g. `isSearchFinished.isAllServicesFinished` should be `isSearchFinished."isAllServicesFinished"`. The same for the rest of them.

Comment: Better yet avoid double quotes, then the issue of mixed case does not exist.  Use or avoid mixed case as you want, Posgres will coerce then to lower case for processing but otherwise leave them alone,